# Prove {$(x, y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 : x \notin \Bbb{Z}$} is open

Tags: general-topology

Having trouble proving this set is open. I can kind of see it visually but don't even know where to begin. Maybe somewhere with $\Bbb{Q} \setminus \Bbb{Z}$?

Comment: Consider (x,y) in this set you write above. Therefore, x is not an integer.
If you take a ball with center (x,y) and radius anything smaller that the distance of the closest integer from x, the ball is inside the initial set.

Answer (score 1):

This set is the inverse image of the open subset $\Bbb R\setminus \{0\}$ of $\Bbb R$ under the continuous function $f:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$ given by $f(x,y)=\sin(\pi x)$.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by realizing $\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ | \ x \notin \mathbb{Z} \}$ as the preimage of some continuous function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow Y$.

For any product of topological spaces $\displaystyle X = \prod_{i \in I} X_i$ endowed with the [product topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology), the [natural projections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(set_theory)) $\pi_i: X \rightarrow X_i$ are continuous.  In our scenario, one can show that the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is equivalent to the metric topology we're familiar with.  So let's consider the projection map $\pi_1$ defined such that $(x,y) \mapsto x$.  It is easier to see that $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$.  What is $\pi_1^{-1}( \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z})$?

---

See Arthur's answer, which uses the same method but a different continuous function.

---

Alternatively, looking at the definition of the product topology, you'll see that $\displaystyle \prod_{i \in I} U_i$ is an open set in $\displaystyle \prod_{i \in I} X_i$ if each $U_i$ is open in $X_i$ (and $U_i \neq X_i$ for only finitely many $i$).  Notice that both $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ itself are open in $\mathbb{R}$.  Therefore, $\left( \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z} \right) \times \mathbb{R} = \Big\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ | \ x \notin \mathbb{Z} \Big\}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Consider the complement instead.

$$\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x \notin \mathbb{Z} \}^c=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x \in \mathbb{Z} \}$$

Consider what are the limit points of the complement set.

Answer (score 0):

The set equals the union of a collection of open sets $\{ (n,n+1)\times\Bbb R\, :\, n \in\Bbb Z \}$